# How can I model a decorative serving tray?

Tags: modeling

[image]

How can i model this? like beautiful line up modeling

I create the the outline and solidified it like this

[image]

But I don't know what to do afterwards.

I tried to bevel, but it doesn't work

Next I try to add subdivison surface, but my blender is dead....

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao4Yx0pJrqq5j8VghFhNK0cV_-NSEQ

Comment: What is "this object"?  A decorative serving tray? Please consider editing title with something a little more specific.

Answer (score 4):

You can:

- Keep only a flat segment, simplify it as much as possible (actually it will depend on if you plan to use a *Subdivision Surface* modifier at the end) and mirror (enable the *Clipping* option of the *Mirror* modifier):

[image]

- Create an empty a the center of the object, give your object an *Array* modifier, choose a *Count* of 8, disable *Relative Offset*, enbable *Object Offset* with the empty as *Object*:

[image]

- Rotate the empty 45° on the Z axis:

[image]

- Move the segment so that it doesn't overlap its instances, extrude inwards:

[image]

- Extrude to give thickness with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*:

[image]

- Make sure you don't create inner faces, if so, delete them:

[image]

- Add geometry and bvels where needed:

[image]

- Apply the modifiers, close the center, merge the vertices by distnace, stretch on the X axis:

[image]

Comment: definitively the easy way for a newbie LOL...

Comment: wow you are best......thanks  a lot it is so easy tutorial thangk!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple starting profile part and add some modifiers:

[image]

That allows to simplify your modelling, handle muc less vertices and adjust things easily before finishing the model.

the modifiers are the following:

[image]

- Mirror as each part is symmetrical
- Array to tune the amount of parts
- Simple deform/bend to round the shape
- Weld to remove doubled vertices
- Subdivision

Additionally the object is stretched to be oval (parented to an empty that is scaled along an axis).

The main interest is to give the ability to change the model easily:

[image]

When happy with the result, you can apply all the modifiers (except the subdivision, maybe) and grid fill the inner part.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this is a bit complex to explain in several steps, so here i gonna leave the blend file [image] , and some steps of how i made it...
1- add circle, press ctrl+2 to add surf-subdiv modifier and start deforming the vertices as wished...
[image]
2- bevel some of those vertices, and slide some of them...
[image]
3- add one vertex in the center, and select 2 verts and conect them to make a 2 edges, and then select the other boundary vertices and press f to fill it...
[image]
4- start adding some cuts with the knife tool, and then smooth it out a bit...
[image]
5- then use insert faces to extrude several loops of faces down, and then smooth several times this faces, and add more support loops to the edges and add topology to needed areas to create the pinching......
[image]
7- then when you are done, select all the mesh and extrude it down, flatten it, and smooth several times, and add some loops to the edges...
[image]
[image]
try as possible to get beautiful topology like this <3...takes some time to master topology i have to say...
[image]
Tip: use symetrize option in edit mode, or mirror modifier for more quick editing and equal symmetry as possible...

Comment: So as you have 4 symmetrical parts don't you use a Mirror modifier? (Except it looks like a 8 sections plate)

Comment: yes, but i applied it